# When call API brings data once yes once no

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this issue with Node JS, if I just insert a new entries (from MYSQL or Postman), when I want to retrieve those entries (called boats) filtering by user, I got information once yes (all information comes properly) and if I try it a second time don't works. It's  interspersed, if I try a third time works fine, but doesn't brings info for fourth time. What can be the issue?

Additional info:

1. If I call the stored procedure directly in MySQL this error doesn't happen, always brings `correct_info`.
2. After some time (4 or 5 min) the API works properly for all the times I call the service.
3. If I reset the server turning off and on the "nodemon", the API is always going to work properly

Database connection file

```
const mysql = require('mysql');
//const mysql = require('mysql2');
const util = require ('util');
 
const pool = mysql.createPool({
     connectionLimit: 10,
     host: 'x.xxx.xx.xxx',
     user: 'xxxxx-xxx',
     password: 'xxxxxxxxxxxx',
     database: 'xxxxxxxxxxxx',
     port: 3306,
     queueLimit: 1000, 
});
 
pool.getConnection((err,connection)=> {
     if(err) throw err;
     console.log('Database connected successfully');
     connection.release();
});
         
        
module.exports = pool;
```

This is the controller:

```
const trxModel = require('../models/trxModels');
 
// Async
const getboatsummaryAsync = util.promisify(trxModel.boatsummary);
 
exports.boatsummary = async (req, res) => {
     try {
         const input = req.params.usercode;
         const response_data = await getboatsummaryAsync(input) // Call user model
 
         if (!response_data){
             return res.status(404).json({ error: 'User not found in DB' });
         }
 
         return res.status(200).json(response_data);
     
     } catch (error) {
         console.log('Error in boatSummary: ', error)
         return res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal server error' });
     } };
```

Finally, this is the model file:

```
const db = require('../config/database.js');
 
const db = require('../config/database.js');
    static async boatsummary(input, callback) {
 
     const sql = 'CALL sp_get_boat_summary(?);'; 
     
     await db.query(sql, [input], function (error, results) { 
         console.log(input);
         if (error)  return callback(error, null);  
 
         const formattedResults = results[0].map((row) => ({ ...row }));
 
         return callback(null,formattedResults);
     });
     
 }
```

Comment: You get any errors in your logs?

Comment: No, I don't have any log. Don't know if something is getting stucked in some buffer and I have to clean it. Because if I reset Nodemon it works perfectly.